# Why can't I hit my WCF service from the outside of the machine, but I can locally?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, self-hosting

I have a WCF Self Hosted service running on a machine with IIS configured. The self hosted service starts with no problem and I can actually access the ?wsdl path once it is up and running.

If I try to hit the following addresses on the machine it loads up the Web page talking about svcutil.exe and how to access the service.

```
http://myspecialservice:9000/
http://192.168.1.230:9000/
```

However, if I try to hit that same address from another machine. I get nothing. No errors, the page just can't be loaded. And I have tested to make sure I am resolving to the right IP Address when I use the hostname.

Also, I have configured for the .exe of the service to be allowed in Windows Firewall With Advanced Security. For all Ethernet Profiles, and any port. Any advice would help out a lot. Again, I know the service is accessible locally on the machine and that it works properly. It seems I am missing a machine configuration somewhere.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TextWriter" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="trace.log"/>
        <add name="Console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
        <remove name="Default"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client/>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.Data.Service" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <clear/>
        <endpoint address="JobsHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.Data.IWhereItSits" bindingConfiguration="CustomHttpBinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" name="httpmex" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://myspecialservice:9000/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

**EDIT 1**

So opening up port 9000 on the firewall instead of specifying a rule for the service.exe allowed me to hit the service on the local network. Now I am trying to hit the service from the outside world. I have added a rule to my router to push any traffic from port 9000 to the server itself but I am not getting anything.

**EDIT 2**

I have installed Network Monitor onto the web server and I can confirm that the router is passing the traffic back to the server itself. And then the server tries to send a response back.

**EDIT 3**

Makes no sense to me whatsoever. The server has two nics, I was targeting 1 IP from the router to the server. I changed it to the other IP and it works from the outside, any explanations or answers?

Comment: How about changing the baseAddress in the config file to match the address you want the service to be reachable from?

Comment: You are using IIS, not IIS-Express?  (the latter does not allow remote connections by default)

Comment: Correct using IIS. I have tried changing the base address and it doesnt seem to matter.

Comment: Your IIS binding for the WCF Service is "all unassigned" or an IP address (should not be 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: I checked that as well. Looks like opening up port 9000 on the firewall instead of specifying the service.exe helped me access the service on the local network. Now I am trying to route traffic from the outside world to the service itself. I have added the port 9000 on the router and have it pointing to the server but I get nothing.

Comment: How are you testing it "from the outside world"?  On a 3G phone or a friend's internet connection or something?  The reason I ask is sometimes depending on the network you can't access services hosted on the local network via their external IPs.  If you are indeed on the outside and it still can't load, how are you determining the external IP?  Setting up port forwarding and opening the firewalls should be all you need to do.  So it could be you're not pointing it to the right IP?

Comment: @Phill What would you recommend as an alternative?

Comment: You're only using HTTP Endpoints, so. NancyFX, ServiceStack. Or if you're scared to use non-ms stuff, WebAPI.

Comment: I am just trying to add the WCF service as a refereance, Add Service Reference. Where I can do that locally, I am trying to hit it from its outside IP address which is static. I am at home trying to access the business IP. I also have business class internet here so I doubt it is an internet issue. Mostly I would feel it is an issue with the ports and protocols?? Idk

Comment: Well that is what I thought, but it is a very basic router. I have port forwarding setup on that router for the port 80 traffic to hit the same server, maybe that is the problem? Even though I have specified port 9000 to also go to the same server?

Comment: Does the traffic from the outside to that server over port 80 work?

Comment: Yes I have websites that work perfectly.

Comment: You could use the netsh command to add port 9000 register for http traffic as well as shown: netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9000/ user=\everyone and one that command is executed i guess if you access your self hosted service from outside the machine it should be accessible.Just make sure of using the correct machinename which can be obtained using hostname command in cmd

Answer (score 0):

You say in your edits that you were able to reach your server, but 192.168.1.230 is a local address. It is only valid from within your local network. Your ip address for the outside world is different. :/

---

Edit

What is your IIS listening to? Maybe you have your bindings (IIS->your site->right click->Edit bindings) set to the other ip only. If so changing IP Address to 'All Unasigned' should make your service respond the first ip as well.

Comment: that is why in the other edits it talks about use of a router

Comment: let me check on this, just now saw this edit I didn't have any notifications.